# Passing parameters to a html file

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

my problem is that I am expanding my website to a mobile version. So I've created a script to check user's screen size and redirect to the mobile version. That works perfectly! But now, I want to create a link in the mobile version to the desktop version. So, I figured out that it would be possible to include some parameters in the URL to alert the script that the user don't want to be redirected to the mobile version. Something like that: **href="desktoppage.htm?mode='desktop'"**. The problem is the link is not working (error 404 - page not found). I guess, because of the parameter the hiperlink is being misinterpreted. **Is there a way to do that without having to change all my pages to js or php?** Pardon my poor english. Thanks.

Comment: what code did you try? please edit your post and include code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
href="desktoppage.htm?mode='desktop'"
```

To this

```
href="desktoppage.htm?mode=desktop"
```

I don't think href lets you put quotes around values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a mobile version of your site, why not just adjust the CSS to use [Media Queries](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)? There's plenty of resources out there to help you get started on that. **You don't have to mess with the existing HTML version of your site**, and it'll automatically adjust the layout based on the type of screen your users are using.

[CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) has a good list of queries for [standard devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) that you can start with. You basically fill in those braces with the special code you want to run for those particular devices. You can probably combine many of them, and remove the "Desktops and Laptops" version so that it would be default. Make sure you place these definitions after your main css!